how does the error "Series' object is not callable" apply in this case?
i have this code which probably has errors of other kinds but the hang  up i'm being given is that "" item_value = str(df.iloc[n] (axis=0)) "" series object is not callable. i'm not sure how or why it is not callable.
def item_total():
    
    n=0
    col_entries = len(df.axes[1])
    item_str = ""
    for i in df.index:
        for k in range(col_entries):
            if n < col_entries and df.iloc[i, n] != np.nan:
                item_value = str(df.iloc[n] (axis=0))
                
                item_str = item_str + item_value
            n = n + 1
            
        print(item_value)

i was expecting the the method to add up all elements of each row and total their string values in a new column displaying the sum of the item string values, excluding NaN values.

df.iloc(axis=0)[n] would be valid (although no different than df.iloc[n])

very good, both methods resolved the issue.  i have some other issue in my code as it resulted in an endless loop. your insight has given me clarity in my error.

When you write df.iloc[n](axis=0), you're asking the DataFrame for the n-th (0 indexed) row, which it returns as a Series, and then trying to call it as a function. That's the brackets there. You pass to the function the keyword axis=0.
Do you mean df.iloc[n].sum(axis=0), which would be a real method/function? More diagnostics may require actual data to be provided along with the expected result.
